# Calendar entries showing up on wrong date

Tags: iphone, calendar

All of a sudden calendar entries are showing up on the day before, instead of on the date entered on my iPhone 6. Example: a meeting entered at 10:00 Monday, October 24 is showing up on Sunday, Oct 23.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say whether this is to do with your phone or another device, but it's possible it's a time zone issue.

You might check that your phone is set to the correct time zone (Settings > General > Date & Time). There's also a time zone override option for the calendar (Settings > Calendar > Time Zone Override) which if enabled will override the time zone of your phone and show your appointments according to the override.

Comment: I had this problem and it turned out to be the Time Zone Override setting, which I was never aware of but had somehow got changed - thanks!